# Problem 14 from Baby Rudin chapter 3

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $\{s_n\}$ is a complex sequence, define its arithmetic means $\sigma_n$ by $$\sigma_n=\dfrac{s_0+s_1+\dots+s_n}{n+1},\quad a_n=s_n-s_{n-1} \quad\text{for} \quad n\geqslant 1$$
Assume $M<\infty,$ $|na_n|\leqslant M$ for all $n$, and $\lim \sigma_n=\sigma$. Prove that $\lim s_n=\sigma$.

**Proof:** There are some hints in book. First of all, choosing any $\varepsilon >0$ and associate with each $n$ the integer $m$ that satisfies $$m\leqslant \frac{n-\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}<m+1 $$ Then $\frac{n-m-1}{m+2}\leqslant \varepsilon.$ Also if $m<n$ (also for NEGATIVE $m$) we have identity $$s_n-\sigma_n=\frac{m+1}{n-m}(\sigma_n-\sigma_m)+\frac{1}{n-m}\sum \limits_{i=m+1}^{n}(s_n-s_i).$$

For these $i$, $$|s_n-s_i|\leqslant \frac{M(n-i)}{i+1}\leqslant \frac{M(n-m-1)}{m+2}.$$Then $$|s_n-\sigma_n|\leqslant \frac{|m+1|}{n-m}|\sigma_n-\sigma_m|+\frac{M(n-m-1)}{|m+2|}\leqslant \frac{|m+1|}{n-m}|\sigma_n-\sigma_m|+M\varepsilon.$$And I have the main question. Can I fixed $m$ and keeping $n\to \infty$. Is it legal? If it's legal then we have: $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|s_n-\sigma_n|\leqslant M\varepsilon$$

Comment: Based on the relation $$ m\leq \frac{n-\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}< m+1$$ I should say no, because you pair $(n,m)$ must satisfy this and make $n\to\infty$ imply $m\to\infty$.

Comment: @MrSelberg, But why [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409481/limit-of-arithmetic-means)(similar problem) we can fixed $N$ and keeping $n\to \infty$? Can you explain this?  It would be great!

Comment: Let's see $N$. "For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|t_n|<\varepsilon$". In this case, the unique relation betwenn $n$ and $N$ is $n\geq N$. Then I can take $n\to\infty$ and this will not change $N$. Moreover, I can not take $N\to \infty$ (for example) beacuse this will imply $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @MrSelberg, Why you cannot take $N\to \infty$? Then $n\to \infty$. So what's the problem?

Comment: What I wanted to point out it that you can't make $N\to\infty$ and keep $n$ fixed.

Comment: @MrSelberg, Thank you very much for help!

Comment: @MrSelberg, Can I ask you the last question? Keeping $m\to\infty$ we also have that $n\to \infty$ then $\limsup_{m\to \infty} |s_n-\sigma_n|\leqslant....$. But how to change this limit to $n\to \infty$?

Comment: @MrSelberg, It would be greatful if you explain this because i see this feint often but can not understand this.

Comment: The $\limsup$ as you wrote make the impression that you can't, 'cause the lim is over $m$ and the term "does not have" relation with $m$ (but we know they do have a relation). Write it in the following way $$\limsup_{\substack{m\to\infty\\ n>m}}|s_n-\sigma_n|,$$
which is equivalent in our case. This can be transformed into a $n$-limit:
$$\limsup_{\substack{m\to\infty\\ n>m}}|s_n-\sigma_n|=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|s_n-\sigma_n|.$$
All this due to the discussion we had in the comments above.