# Prove that if lim $a_n=L$ then lim $p_n=L$, with $p_n= \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to do this:

Prove that if lim $a_n=L$ then lim $p_n=L$, with $p_n= \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. And show that the converse is false.

What I have done is:

a)Due to $a_n=L$ exists $N$ such that $|a_n-L|< \frac{\epsilon}2$ $\forall n>N$

\begin{align}
\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k-L\right|&=\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-L)\right|\\\\
&\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^N|a_k-L|+\frac1n\sum_{k=N+1}^n|a_k-L|
\end{align}

After using the triangular inequality and using a) I can say second term must be less than $\frac{n-N}n(\frac\epsilon 2)< \frac\epsilon2$

The problem is with the term $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^N|a_k-L|$. What can I use to say this is less than $\frac\epsilon2$ to conclude that $|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k-L|=\epsilon$?

Any ideas?

Comment: Since $N$ is fixed, you just let $n$ runs so that $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^N|a_k-L|<\frac {\epsilon}2$ eventually.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409481/limit-of-arithmetic-means

Answer (score 0):

Let's give a rigorous proof here.

Given $\epsilon > 0$

First since  lim $a_n=L$, there exist $N_0$ such that

Since a convergence sequence is bounded so there exist $M >0$  such that $a_k < M \, \forall \, k \in \mathbb{N} $

Again since  lim $a_n=L$, there exist an $N_1$ such that $ L - \epsilon< a_n< L + \epsilon  \,\,\,\forall n > N_1 $

Now for $n > N_1,$

$|p_n - L |= |\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{n} - L|  = |\sum_{k=1}^{N_1} \frac{a_k}{n} - L(N_1) + \sum_{k=N_1+1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{n} - L(n-N_1)| $

$\leq   |\frac{MN_1-LN_1}{n}| + |\sum_{k=N_1+1}^{n} \frac{L+ \epsilon}{n}  -L(n-N_1) |$

$\leq |\frac{MN_1-LN_1}{n}| + |\frac{(n-N_1)(L+ \epsilon)}{n}  -\frac{L(n-N_1)}{n} | $

$\leq |\frac{MN_1-LN_1}{n}| + |\frac{(n-N_1)\epsilon}{n}| $

take $n \rightarrow \infty$, we get $|p_n - L | \leq \epsilon$

Comment: You're treating $L$ as though it's inside the sum.  Isn't that wrong?